# scheduled script doesn't run as expected

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, windows-task-scheduler

So I have scheduled a task to run some script at windows shutdown through task scheduler, the trigger is an event its source is USER32 its ID is 1074.
I have made some shortcut placed on my desktop to shutdown my computer its code is:

```
shutdown /s
```

the problem is whenever I try to shutdown my computer using this shortcut the scheduled script run as expected. But whenever I try to shutdown using the normal way (start > shutdown), the scheduled script doesn't run as expected.
when viewing event log the case of the shortcut its says EXPLORER.exe initiated a shutdown, the case of the normal method says C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe initiated a shutdown. 
I don't know why the script doesn't run as expected when I shutdown using the normal way.
Ps: the scheduled scripts does copy the estimated charge remaining in the battery and shutdown time to some text file placed in my desktop.

Comment: If you don't provide a time, then 30 seconds is assumed, I am going to guess you don't want any delay.  If that is the case then you should be using `shutdown /s /f /t 0` or simply `shutdown /s /t 0` instead of the command your using.  You might want to force the shutdown, this will close any open applications forcefully, so I suggest you test without it.  Proper [research](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416(v=ws.11).aspx) is the key to solving any problem.

Comment: Exactly!!! and part of that research is asking questions in the right place

Comment: You can’t use `shutdown` to shutdown a system that is already shutting down. You’ll just be told the system is already shutting down. You do understand that using a trigger based on the system shutting down to run the `shutdown` command really makes no sense, right? What are you REALLY trying to accomplish here?